# Memory consumption when creating a Dataframe from a 2D array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big file that I have to transform in a dataframe. The file has 1 item per line and I must convert that to a dataframe. For that I read to a 2D array and every time I encounter -99999 I have to change the row of the 2D array.

When I create the dataframe, I get a memory problem if the file is too big :

*MemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.3GiB for an Array with shape (2735, 555873)*

It tries to allocate 11.3GiB extra but it has at least the same amount already in use from what I saw in my memory consumption.

Any tips on how to improve the memory usage?

```
        temperature_matrix = []  # All the temperature, this serves as data for the dataframe
        time_array = []  # The array of temperature, this serves as index for the dataframe
        elements = []  # The array of elements, this serves as columns title for the dataframe

        with open(self.file_location, "r") as f:
            timestep = -1  # no of time steps

            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                line_data = line.split()

                if line_data[0] == "-99999":  # Detecting a new time step, we skip
                    time_array.append(float(line_data[1]))
                    timestep = timestep + 1
                    temperature_matrix.append([])
                    continue

                if timestep == 0:  # For the first timestep we store the element ids
                    elements.append(int(line_data[0]))

                temperature_matrix[timestep].append(float(line_data[1]))

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=temperature_matrix, index=time_array, columns=elements)
```

See example of input file:

```
-99999 0.0  # Time step 0
125 25.774447 # Temperature of element 125 at time step 0
126 35.774447
127 45.774447
128 55.774447
...
-99999 60.0  # Time step 60.0
125 25.774447 # Temperature of element 125 at time step 60
126 35.774447
127 45.774447
128 55.774447
...
```

I tried to round the float but the memory consumption is the same.

Comment: You'll need to give us more details about the input data. It's nice to know that there's "1 item per line", but you don't really tell us what each item consists of (we can only infer that it's probably some integer followed by a real number representing a temperature). What's the range of the temperature? What resolution is required (you mention you tried rounding it -- does that mean you don't care about the decimal point?). Is there the same number of measurements for each "element" or do those differ?

Comment: The rounding probably didn't make a difference because you let pandas infer the datatype to use and first it picked a 64bit float, and second time a 64bit integer -- both of those seem rather excessive for a temperature measurement. | "but it has at least the same amount already in use" -- that's the original lists, and then you need to allocate new memory for the DataFrame. You'll need to preallocate the DataFrame and populate it directly to avoid this. Make two passes -- in first determine the number of rows/columns you need, in second pass populate the data.

Comment: I have edited my question to add an example

Comment: Good, but what about my other questions? Even if you need to keep 6 decimal places, you could still do with just a 32bit float in the DataFrame. But it seems unlikely you're making measurements that precise. To be even more memory efficient, you could scale the values to be representable by a 16bit integer, perhaps 100ths of a degree...